# How can i separate WHMCS css and my own HTML css code

Tags: html, css, integration, whmcs

I downloaded a template that i want to use on my new website.
I also want's to integrate it with WHMCS, but when i try to do it WHMCS get affected by my CSS code that my HTML website have.

Is there easy way to separate these 2 different CSS classes?

Comment: Could you change your site and your CSS to be different from the template's CSS? I'm assuming that since they're yours, you have the ability to modify them.

Comment: I have the whole code css and html

Comment: But in the templates css file there is over 10000 lines of code

Comment: @ShotgunNinja do you know how i can do this?